# Can't stop writing. Allow me to Escape textboxes

Tags: bug, comments, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using keyboard shortcuts on sites where I'm interested in moderating and general janitorial duties. For that I regularly use combinations like `m + c + [num] + [num]`.

In and of itself this is not a problem, though the dialog sometimes isn't fast enough :/ Alas I'll slow down a little and it's usually fine.

What's worse is when I don't hit the `m` correctly or the post I want to moderate isn't selected already. Then the cursor often jumps into the comment box (`c` ftw.) and suddenly I'm locked.

I cannot escape the comment box short of using my mouse to unfocus. This defeats the whole point of keyboard shortcuts.

**Can I please use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to unfocus the current text input?**

This includes:

- Tag inline editing box
- Post edit
- Comment
- Answer composing

Comment: Why not using TAB?

Comment: Have you tried Tab, Shift+Tab?

Comment: I'm concerned that while [Esc] makes a lot of sense for things like popups, it isn't an expected mechanism for a pre-existing permanent UI element. I kinda have to agree with @ShadowWizard here - tab away. Ultimately, that is what we would have to do *anyway*.